# W3C, Google Gears and Loki Geolocation based on what?

Tags: c#, geolocation, w3c, google-gears

I understand that these are client-side apps, but all three must be based on some component of the computer itself.

Which component is this, and how can I utilize it programmatically for a C# app (NOT FOR WEB)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're client-side, and they use different sources for the location information. The W3C API in Firefox uses Google Location Services (a JSON API) and I bet Google Gears uses the Google database as well, while Loki uses the Skyhook Wireless service. And different browsers who implement the W3C API can use different location services. Mobile Safari uses Skyhook, or GPS info from the device itself.

You could look at any of these providers for accessing location through your desktop app. Google Location Services appears to be a particularly simple web API, but I think you can also get programmatic access to Skyhook. Since you're writing in C#, you might look into the Windows 7 Location Platform, which provides an easy-to-use OS-level framework that abstracts away the different providers.

(Sorry for any typos and the lack of links; answer posted from my tablet.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a version of geolocation using skyhook wireless sdk.And here is another link for you it is called WPS(wi-fi positioning system)[enter link description here][1]

http://www.j2i.net/BlogEngine/post/2008/12/30/Accessing-the-Skyhook-Wireless-SDK-from-C-prerelease-wrapper.aspx